# Is $\cos(a(\pi-t))$ an even function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, even-and-odd-functions

I've an assignment due in a couple of days, and I'm wondering if my teacher made a mistake in the question below, or if I'm missing something silly.

Let $a \in [0, 1]$ and $f_a$ the $2\pi$-periodic function defined as $f_a(t) = \cos(a(π − t))$
for $t ∈ [0, 2π]$.

Show that $f_a$ is continuous and even.

I've tried proving $f_a(t)=f_a(-t)$ with Euler and trigonometry formula to no avail.
Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your $f_a$ does not have period $2\pi$.

Comment: Probably you need to use the hypothesis that it is $2\pi$ periodic to restrict what $a$ can be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the periodicity of $f_a$.  Previously, I suggested take $t=1, a=\frac 13$.  We get
$$f_{1/3}(1)=\cos((\pi-1)/3)\approx 0.756\\
f_{1/3}(-1)=\cos((\pi+1)/3)\approx 0.189$$
But this is not correct.  $f_a(t)$ is defined by starting with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ (should be $t \in [0,2\pi[$ to avoid a conflict) and then invoking periodicity.  So
$$f_{1/3}(-1)=f_{1/3}(2\pi-1)=\cos((\pi-(2\pi-1))/3)=\cos((-\pi+1)/3)\approx 0.756$$  You can use the fact that $\cos (\pi-x)$ is symmetric around $\pi$ because $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try picking some arbitrary value of $a$ (or even just $a=1/2$) and plotting the function? Sure doesn't look even to me.

A plot is not a proof but you can also use the angle sum formulas,
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{t}{2}\right) = \cos\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\frac{t}{2} + \sin\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\frac{t}{2} = \sin\frac{t}{2},$$
which is clearly not even.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $a \in ]0, 1[$ and $f_a$ the 2π-periodic function defined as $f_a(t) = \cos(a(π − t))$
> for $t ∈ [0, 2π[$.

> Show that $f_a$ is continuous and even.

It is true that (for example) 
$\cos(\pi - \theta) = \cos(\pi + \theta).$

So, the assertion is true if $a$ happens to equal $1$, because you end up comparing
$\cos(\pi - t)$ versus $\cos(\pi + t)$.

Further, if the assertion was changed to 
$f_a = \cos[\pi - (at)]$, 
rather than $f_a = \cos[a(\pi - t)]$, 
then the assertion would again be true, for the same reason.

What has gone wrong, which makes the assertion false, is that instead of comparing
$\cos[\pi - (at)]$ versus $\cos[\pi + (at)]$ you are comparing $\cos[(a\pi) - (at)]$ versus $\cos[(a\pi) + at].$

This means that instead of having the *central angle* about which the angle $\theta$ is reflected
be the angle $\pi$, the central angle is $(a\pi)$.

This makes me wonder whether there is a typo in the problem.  That is, I wonder whether the OP (i.e. original poster) has mistranslated the original assertion.